# Sklearn kmeans causes Mac OS pyinstaller app crash

Tags: python, tkinter, scikit-learn, pyinstaller

I'm creating a piece of software using tkinter and pyinstaller that imports KMeans from sklearn.cluster:

The software as an .exe works fine on Windows 11
The GUI works fine before packaging using pyinstaller on Mac Monterey
The software as an .app works fine on Mac if I don't import KMeans from sklearn.cluster
If I do import KMeans from sklearn.cluster the bundled .app file crashes

I'm using Python 3.7
Scikit-learn (version 1.0.2)
Newest pyinstaller (version 5.6.2)

I've tried removing the import (software as an .app works on Mac).

I've tried upgrading scikit-learn and pyinstaller.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

Apparently there were issues with sklearn not being included in hidden imports in the past [issue here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/3911)

However, this couldn't be the issue, because my PC version was working. I'm using pyinstaller on Windows to bundle an .exe and pyinstaller on Mac to bundle an .app

[This issue](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/6035) lead me to believe it may be an issue with my environment. Creating a new environment from scratch worked, and now my .app opens.